# Recaptcha problem on localhost

Tags: php, recaptcha

Hey guys, I'm trying to use recaptcha on local host. I got a global public/private key and I'm using this code:

```
<form name="registration_form" method="post" action="register.php" onsubmit="return Validate();"><input type=hidden name=todo value=post>
            <table>
            <tr><td class="label">First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label">Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label">E-Mail Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label">Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label">Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="label">Password Confirmation:</td><td><input type="password" name="password_confirmation"></td></tr>
            <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "****"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                ?>
            <tr><td class="label"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Recaptchalib is in the same place as signup.php so that's not the problem. But after Password confirmation, i get nothing. A blank page.

Here's the error.

Warning: require_once(/var/www/JMToday/recaptchalib.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/JMToday/signup.php on line 44 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'recaptchalib.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/JMToday/signup.php on line 44

Comment: Could you paste your error log of your web server here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that the /var/www directory has read permissions for the user you run your web server as.

Alternatively, run:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/JMToday/recaptchalib.php
```

which will give total control to the owner of the file and read rights to anyone else.

Comment: I guess so, I think I would've ran into other similar problems if not since when the php code wasn't there I was simply redirected to register.php . Also in permisions the permissions for the user is read and write and for others is read an write to.